# There is a gap between grid items that's not supposed to be there

Tags: html, css

I am cloning this webpage:
https://zunnykim.wixsite.com/ancellbioa/pdt-pipeline

My end product must look like it.

```css
#BG_1706683795992_15969 {
  display: grid;
}

#BG_1706683808231_83031 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 3 / 1;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 3 / 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 41, 0.7);
}

#BG_1706683829871_20680 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 4 / 1 / 4 / span 3;
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 4 / span 3;
  height: 200px;
}

#BG_1706683877628_36798 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  width: 850px;
  height: 280px;
  background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/%ED%8F%AC%ED%86%A0%EC%A7%84.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

#BG_1706683905743_44938 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
  width: 850px;
  height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  order: 0;
}

#BG_1706683924926_52788 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 2;
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 2;
  width: 850px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
}

#BG_1706683978083_43907 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 3 / 3;
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 3 / 3;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 41, 0.7);
}

#BG_1706685254015_12934 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
}

#BG_1706685271446_57704 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  background-image: url("%EC%9B%90%EB%8D%B0%EC%9D%B4%EB%A9%B4%EC%97%AD-10.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 160px;
}

#text_below_items {
  -webkit-grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}

#BG_1706685935464_87845 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Bahnschrift";
}

#BG_1706687400491_80512 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Bahnschrift";
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#BG_1706687504795_85541 {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#BG_1706688379091_93387 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
}

#BG_1706688397464_74555 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
}

#BG_1706688917242_86833 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
}

#BG_1706689145082_85616 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#BG_1706519208740_25601 {
  border-style: none;
}

#BG_1706519208740_25601 {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: "Bahnschrift";
  background-color: #003333;
  margin: 40px;
}

#BG_1706689794951_83534 {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

#BG_1706689866111_74675 {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Fotoditazin / ANCelltazin® Discovery</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/Fotoditazin%20_%20ANCelltazin%C2%AE%20Discovery.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container" id="BG_1706683795992_15969">
      <div id="BG_1706683808231_83031"> 1 </div>
      <div id="BG_1706683829871_20680" style="text-align: center; background-color: #000030;"><span

          style="color: white; font-family: avenir-lt-w01_35-light1475496,avenir-lt-w05_35-light,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.14px; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;"

          id="BG_1706689866111_74675">© 2020 by ANCell-bio co.LTD</span></div>
      <div id="BG_1706683877628_36798"> 3 </div>
      <div id="BG_1706683924926_52788"> &nbsp;
        <div id="BG_1706688379091_93387" style="text-align: right;"><img src="file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/KakaoTalk_20240201_131109761.jpg"

            alt="" style="width: 462px; height: 223px;"><img src="file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/%ED%99%88%ED%8E%98%EC%9D%B4%EC%A7%80%20%EC%86%8C%EC%8A%A4-05.png"

            alt="" id="BG_1706689794951_83534" style="width: 315px; height: 276px;"></div>
        <div style="text-align: center; margin: 20px 0"> <a href="PDT%20LAB.html"

            id="BG_1706519208740_25601" style="color: white;">&nbsp;&nbsp;BACK&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="BG_1706683905743_44938"><br>
        <div id="BG_1706685935464_87845"> Fotoditazin / ANCelltazin®<br>
          Discovery </div>
        <div id="BG_1706685271446_57704"><br>
        </div>
        <div id="text_below_items">
          <h1 id="BG_1706687400491_80512"> ANCelltazin® PDT Drug accumulate in
            cancer cell only </h1>
          <p id="BG_1706687504795_85541"> Selective necrosis of tumor cells
            without damage to normal cells, excretion of residual
            photosensitizer through metabolism </p>
          <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/%ED%99%88%ED%8E%98%EC%9D%B4%EC%A7%80%20%EC%86%8C%EC%8A%A4-04.png"

              alt="" style="width: 712px; height: 131px;"><br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr style="width: 750px; height: 1px; color: #000066; border-style: solid; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="BG_1706683978083_43907"> 6 </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have used css grid to make the layout for my webpage. However although I can see no error in my css grid, a white gap keeps on appearing between the right grid item that spans down the right hand side of the page with navy background, and the 3 middle grid items. To be more precise, there is a vertical white gap between grid items BG_1706683877628_36798, BG_1706683905743_44938, BG_1706683924926_52788 and the grid item BG_1706683978083_43907.

I am using a WYSIWYG web builder called BlueGriffon.

Can you help me get rid of this white gap?

Comment: Have you used your browsers devtools to see exactly what CSS is being applied? There is a lot of code shown, and a lot of fixed widths. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example